# как передать ArrayList на сервер (php)?

Tags: java, android

Есть определенный ArrayList заполненный  данными,как мне передать этот массив на сервер?

Comment: конвертнуть в json `JSONArray ar=new JSONArray(myArrayList);
  String json= ar.toString()` и пульнуть?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `JSONObject`.

Пример:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
try {
    jsonObject.put("jsonArray",jsonArray);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```